# Django Form - Passing Values

Tags: python, django

I have the following form and can't seem to use the "self.currentSelectedTeam1" as the initial value for team1 as can be seen at the bottom.  When I do try this I get the following error:

```
team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,initial=self.curentSelectedTeam1)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Form:

```
class SelectTwoTeams(BootstrapForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.curentSelectedTeam1 = kwargs.pop('curentSelectedTeam1', None)
        self.curentSelectedTeam2 = kwargs.pop('curentSelectedTeam2', None)
        super(SelectTwoTeams, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1)

        self.fields['team1'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['team2'].queryset = queryset

    team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,initial=self.curentSelectedTeam1)
    team2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,initial=self.curentSelectedTeam2)
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `self` keyword in team1 and team2 variables. 
The thing is they are on the class-level, and the self is available on the instance level(inside methods, excluding static methods and class methods)

To make it work you need to do the same with `self.fields['team1'].queryset`:

```
self.fields['team1'].initial = self.curentSelectedTeam1
```

inside `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work becasue the fields `team1` and `team2` are created before `__init__` is called because they're instance members.

This means that `self.curentSelectedTeam1` and `self.curentSelectedTeam2` aren't available yet and are most likely `None`.

In order to set initial values on the form, you need to do so when you instantiate the form itself.

```
team1_pk = 0
team2_pk = 1

form = SelectTwoTeams(initial={'curentSelectedTeam1': team1_pk, 'curentSelectedTeam2': team2_pk})
```

You'll need to either remove your current `__init__` override or call `super()` to allow the initial values to be passed to the form's default constructor.

Comment: Sorry I can't award both a correct answer.  Both worked perfectly and I do appreciate your help.  Many thanks, Alan.